# How to add the photos to ReferrenceScreen on android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Now create an Fragment subclass that will show your ImageView and provide a container that will hold your preferences:

```html
public class More : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
            // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

            //return base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MoreLayout,container,false);

        }

        [Obsolete("deprecated")]
        public override void OnAttach (Android.App.Activity activity)
        {
            mainActivity = (MainActivity)activity;
            base.OnAttach (activity);
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
            mainActivity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(Resource.Id.PreferencesContainer, new ReferenceFragment()).Commit();


        }


    }
```

I want to set image inside PreferenceScreen as below picture
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0XvL.jpg)

Create a PreferenceFragment subclass that will display just your preferences, I copy/pasted yours into a file Resources/layout/MyPrefs.xml and than load those in the Fragment's OnCreate:

```
 public class ReferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment
        {
            public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
                AddPreferencesFromResource (Resource.Xml.preferecesSettings);
                // Create your fragment here
            }

            public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
                // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

                return base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via a `PreferenceFragment`.

Create a `PreferenceFragment` *subclass* that will display just your preferences, I copy/pasted yours into a file `Resources/layout/MyPrefs.xml` and then load those in the `Fragment`'s `OnCreate`:

```
public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Layout.MyPrefs);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Now create an `Activity` *subclass* that will show your `ImageView` and provide a container that will hold your preferences:

```
[Activity(Label = "SettingsActivity")]
public class SettingsActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PreferencesLayout);
        FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Add(Resource.Id.PreferencesContainer, new SettingsFragment()).Commit();
    }
}
```

The layout that is being loaded in `Activity` that will show an image and your preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PreferencesImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/PreferenceImage" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/PreferencesContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/PreferencesImage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now just create an `Intent` and start the activity to show your custom preferences:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SettingsActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```

[image]